# Google showing meta descriptions from other pages in the SERPs

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing

Recently I added some content to my website and submitted a sitemap files to Google. Now that Google has indexed those pages, I discovered that some of words and sentences that are listed in Google that lead to my website are having their meta descriptions somehow mixed up.

Here is how it works: After I put a sentence on Google to check for my website ranking, I can see a page title in the results of `page1`, a link to `page1`, and a description from `page2`.

Since my website is a forum, if Google mixes the links of threads, it leads my users to different kind of material that they were looking for. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can you share a link to the search result where this is happening? If your site isn't mixing up the tags itself, then it really sounds like a bug in Google.  One that I have never seen before myself.

Answer (score 0):

If the description of `Page1` is not related to the searched sentence, Google has the capability to take the related description from somewhere else it found.

Comment: Uh, but the description of `Page2` does not relate to `Page1` at all! Also, `Page1` has it's own description. I don't know what to do now...